# Implementar exibição de mensagem "carregando..." no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código em `JavaScript` para postar os dados do formulário no `MySql`. Porém, preciso que exiba a uma mensagem de "carregando..." antes de concluir o envio, pois utilizo para postar fotos e demora um pouco.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    $('#feed_msg').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formDados = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url:'post-msg-grupo.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:formDados,
            cache:false,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function (data)
     {document.getElementById('msginf').innerHTML = 'Parabéns! Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!';
              $('#feed_msg').each (function(){
            this.reset();
           });
      },
            dataType:'html'
        });
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: antes de executar o ajax é só exibir a mensagem... pode ser exibindo um div, ou um simples `document.write("carregando...");`

Comment: @RicardoPontual Sou leigo, onde coloco este código no script que postei?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Tentei mas não funcionou.

Comment: pode ser dentro da função de sumit em qualquer lugar antes do `$.ajax`, antes da linha  `event.preventDefault();` por exemeplo

Comment: @RicardoPontual Deu erro, ele abre uma nova aba no navegador e aparece "carregando..". O corretoé aparecer dentro de 'msginf'

Comment: isso foi só um exemplo, o melhor seria criar um div com a mensagem dentro e exibir o div, que vai estar posicionado em algum lugar que fique bem visível, é que entendi que sua dúvida era como exibir a mensagem apenas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque a mensagem antes do AJAX (`$.ajax({...})`) com o mesmo `innerHTML`, mas você pode usar o jQuery pra isso:

```
$(function(){

    $('#feed_msg').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formDados = new FormData($(this)[0]);

         $('#msginf').html('Carregando...');

        $.ajax({
            url:'post-msg-grupo.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:formDados,
            cache:false,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function (data){
               $('#msginf').html('Parabéns! Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!');
              $('#feed_msg').each (function(){
            this.reset();
           });
      },
            dataType:'html'
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Quando o AJAX entrar no `success`, irá substituir o conteúdo do elemento `#msginf` pela mensagem de "sucesso".

Answer (score 2):

Indente melhor seu código para o entendimento de todos quando for realizar perguntas, facilita a compreensão daqueles que querem te ajudar.
Agora respondendo sua pergunta, dentro do método $.ajax, você pode passar uma propriedade dentro deste objeto que você criou chamada beforeSend, nesta propriedade você cria uma função inline ou chama alguma função de sua preferência, está função irá ser executada antes da requisição ser enviada, então você poderia fazer isso :

```
 $.ajax({ 
      ... //suas outras propriedades
     beforeSend: function() {
         $(".divprincipal").append("<div class='loader'></div>");
     }
     sucess: function(dados) {
        $(".loader").remove();
        //colocar os dados na tela
     }
    });
```

O código acima coloca uma div com a classe "loader" dentro de outra div, e quando a requisição for processada com sucesso (sucess:) você remove ela. Espero ter ajudado :)

Documentação do método $.ajax [aqui](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)